# Adjust width and height of DIV element

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a vertical navbar on the left side of the page, and a "content" area to the right of the navbar.  I want the width of the "content" area to fill the remainder of the screen, and the height to match the navbar height.

Here is what I have so far: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsGN6/)

Preferably I am looking for a pure CSS solution to this problem.

Comment: Will the navbar always be taller than the content?

Comment: I want the navbar height to be the minimum height for the content, so if the content is larger, the div will stretch to fit.

Comment: Do you want the height of the div of the nav area to stretch when there is more content added to the content area?  Sorry, just you answer to @Wex's questions sounded confusing.

Comment: How do you want the extra nav height to fill in? Just with a blank, dark gray, rounded-rectangle background you have? So in other words, the empty space below the links is okay, but you want that rectangle to stretch down as the content grows.

Comment: @PatrickM the navbar doesn't need to grow, empty space below is fine, it is only the content area that i want to grow/shrink as the content is changed.  But if the content is shorter than the navbar length i want the content area to have the same height as the navbar.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ah, so you want to impose a minimum height on the content area. Got it. I think I've seen that done before, just have to find the right tutorial.

Comment: `min-height` css property would get the job done, but you'd have to change the css every time you added another link. I'll hunt around a bit more for an auto-scaling solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) technique is used to fill in the space that isn't filled with content. You'll need to replace your CSS gradients with images, and it's much easier to set up with fixed dimensions (but still possible with fluid dimensions).

Essentially, you'd need to structure your HTML elements like this:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Your CSS would do the work for you as far as stretching the content goes:

```
/* The top part of the rounded container */
#header { 
    background: url(images/bg_top.gif) 100% 100% no-repeat; /* sit on top */
}

/* The background for your content */
#wrapper { 
    background: url(images/bg_tile.gif) 100% 0 repeat-y; /* repeat on the right */
}

/* The bottom of your content */
#footer {
    background: url(images/bg_bottom.gif) 100% 0 no-repeat; /* sit on the bottom */
}
```

You'll definitely need to play around with some negative margins to get things to sit perfectly.

Comment: This is for your "pure CSS solution". You're much better off using JavaScript for this.

Answer (score -1):

Apply a min height to your content area:

```
#content {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height:328px;
}
```

Check out the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hsGN6/6/

It's crude, but it works.

Comment: I was looking for something more flexible than hard-coding in a min-height.  As the navbar grows, i would have to modify the min-height value in your solution.